# Unable to Get this fiddle in page

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle, fiddle

I am trying to make [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaredwilli/tzpg4/4/) work on web page without success. I have done this before but this fiddle is not working.

I tried to add google's jquery or min jquery, without success. I also tried to add javascript code after div instead of in header, still no success.

can anybody help??

Below is my html code....

```
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script>
$(function() {
    var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
    var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;

    $('#addScnt').live('click', function() {
            $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i +'" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
            i++;
            return false;
    });

    $('#remScnt').live('click', function() { 
            if( i > 2 ) {
                    $(this).parents('p').remove();
                    i--;
            }
            return false;
    });
});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
* { font-family:Arial; }
h2 { padding:0 0 5px 5px; }
h2 a { color: #224f99; }
a { color:#999; text-decoration: none; }
a:hover { color:#802727; }
p { padding:0 0 5px 0; }

input { padding:5px; border:1px solid #999; border-radius:4px; -moz-border-radius:4px; -web-kit-border-radius:4px; -khtml-border-radius:4px; }
</style>

</head>

<body>

<h2><a href="#" id="addScnt">Add Another Input Box</a></h2>

<div id="p_scents">
<p>
    <label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label>
</p>
</div>


</form>
</body>
```

Comment: What the code is supposed to do?

Comment: If the fiddle is to add another input box and then remove them one by one on clicking Remove, it is working for me.

Comment: @Rohit416 i want to get same functionality in a web page.

Comment: @Krishnakumar_Muraleedharan i am not talking about fiddle itself. fiddle is working. but the code of the fiddle is not working when used in web page.

Comment: @user6601842 How can anyone judge that. There must something else going on in your web page. Check browser `console` and see if you get anything useful. Besides all that, do not use `live()`, use `on()` or `delegate()`.

Comment: are you getting any error in console ?

Comment: There are some issues with your html. Where is the script inclusion `<script>`?  I cant see a `<form>` tag. but there is an end tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the html you provided, there are few issues.

1: Jquery is not included in your HTML.

2: Live function is obsolete. if you have included Jquery version 1.9 or upwards in you web page but missed to mentioned in the question, then you should use event delegation for the dynamically appended elements.

```
.on(eventType, selector, function)
```

Try like below and it should work.

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
    var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;

    $(document).on('click','#addScnt', function() {
            $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i +'" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
            i++;
            return false;
    });

    $(document).on('click','#remScnt', function() { 
            if( i > 2 ) {
                    $(this).parents('p').remove();
                    i--;
            }
            return false;
    });
});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
* { font-family:Arial; }
h2 { padding:0 0 5px 5px; }
h2 a { color: #224f99; }
a { color:#999; text-decoration: none; }
a:hover { color:#802727; }
p { padding:0 0 5px 0; }

input { padding:5px; border:1px solid #999; border-radius:4px; -moz-border-radius:4px; -web-kit-border-radius:4px; -khtml-border-radius:4px; }
</style>

</head>

<body>
<form>
<h2><a href="#" id="addScnt">Add Another Input Box</a></h2>

<div id="p_scents">
<p>
    <label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label>
</p>
</div>


</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i had included jquery but did not work. May be because it was jquery-1.4.3